Latex: Headlines don't show
I'm very new to latex so this might be a stupid problem, but I was trying to create a document with headlines with multiple lines. I tried following advise on the overleaf page and from different forums, but now my headline just doesn't show up.
This is what I did:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{apacite} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}



\title{Titel}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\textbf{[MyUNi],[MyName],[\date{\today}]}}
\maketitle

As you might be able to see, I was trying to create a headline that always stays on the left side of the page and has multiple lines as that is a requirement in my uni course. I don't know, why the headline doesn't show up and there are no notifications that I might have done something wrong.

\maketitle issues \thispagestyle{empty} so there is no page style on that page (as it should be).
